# Shannon's information theory on open systems

Tags: information

A university professor on [Library and information science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_and_information_science) told me that he considers [Shannon's information theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory) too limited since it doesn't apply to open systems.

I couldn't find info to back up this assertion. Maybe the issue might be related to the definition of *system*.

[One definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System#cite_note-merriam-webster-system-1) is:

> A system is a group of interacting or interrelated elements that act according to a set of rules to form a unified whole.

But a [*physical* system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_system) uses a different definition:

> In physics, a physical system is a portion of the physical universe chosen for analysis. Everything outside the system is known as the environment. The environment is ignored except for its effects on the system.

Both definitions shouldn't contradict (moreover, considering both as part of [system science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_science)). Which definition applies to information theory? The [possible contradictions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/593908/194358) don't apply in this case?

If true, why doesn't Shannon's information theory apply to [open systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_system_(systems_theory))?

### Maybe related

- [2nd law of thermodynamics for an open system](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304382/194358)

### Bibliography

(Given by the professor)

- [Gleick, James (2011) The Information: A History, a Theory, a Flood. (chap 7 y 8)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Information:_A_History,_a_Theory,_a_Flood)
- [Campbell, Jeremy (1989) Grammatical Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_Man)

Comment: Shannon's information theory is concerned with communication channel bandwidth, information rate, source coding, noisy channels, noisy coding, coding rates, error rates, compression losses, coding/decoding delay, etc. What do those concepts have to do with a "system" being "closed" or "open"? What is the "system" your professor had in mind for which Shannon's theory might be inapplicable?

Comment: Related: [Entropy production in non-equilibrium systems: physical interpretation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/312038/247642), [Is information entropy the same as thermodynamic entropy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/263197/247642), [What is an open quantum system?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/299294/247642)